# XElement C#: How to change the value of XElement?

Tags: c#, xelement

I have an element that has some value like:

```
<Element>
     <I id="I01" class="" /> Some Text
</Element>
```

How do I keep the "I" element but change the "Some Text" in the Element Tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the right `XText` child node of `Element` and set the value of that.
Here's an example, which assumes that it's the *first* `XText` node that you're interested in:

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        XElement element= XElement.Parse(@"
<Element>
    <I id=""I01"" class="""" /> Some Text
</Element>");
        element.DescendantNodes().OfType<XText>().First().Value = "New value";
        Console.WriteLine(element);
    }
}
```

Output:

```xml
<Element>
  <I id="I01" class="" />New value</Element>
```